# Упала скорость интернета на Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, сеть

`UPD(подправил описание проблемы):`
Вчера поставил Ubuntu, при скачивании программ заметил что сильно упала скорость интернета, на всем протяжении скачивания скорость наблюдалась не более `100 КБ/сек`, в то время как для Windows 7 нормальным было около `2~3.5 МБ/сек`. Низкая скорость наблюдается не только при скачивании, даже обычный поиск может занять некоторое время, про просмотр видео я даже говорить не буду, начиная уже с `480p` видео заметно начинает тормозить и смотреть становится проблематично. Наблюдаю такую картину уже несколько дней, скорость интернета все так же не высокая.
 При переключении обратно на Windows 7(Ubuntu стоит второй ОС) скорость интернета приходит в норму, никаких проблем нет.

Как исправить данную проблему?

Вот информация(о сети), которую я смог получить с помощью команды
`~$ wavemon`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может быть эта информация поможет кому-то понять в чем проблема.

Вот еще немного информации из `~$ lshw:`

```
*-network
                описание: Ethernet interface
                продукт: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                производитель: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                физический ID: 0
                сведения о шине: pci@0000:03:00.0
                логическое имя: enp3s0
                версия: 06
                серийный №: 90:2b:34:a8:68:33
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                разрядность: 64 bits
                частота: 33MHz
                возможности: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                конфигурация: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
                ресурсы: IRQ:17 ioport:ce00(размер=256) память:fd8ff000-fd8fffff память:fd8f8000-fd8fbfff
```

Результат выполнения команды `~$ dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|r816|error|fail'`:

```
~$ dmesg | egrep -i 'eth|net|r816|error|fail'
[    0.177964] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.178065] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.189127] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189133] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189137] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189141] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189150] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189154] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189157] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189161] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189170] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189174] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189177] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189180] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189190] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189193] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189197] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189200] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189209] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189213] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189216] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189220] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189229] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189233] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189236] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189239] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189249] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189252] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189256] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189259] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189268] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189272] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189275] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189278] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189288] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189291] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189295] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189298] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189307] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189311] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189314] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189317] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189327] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKB (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189330] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189334] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKD (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.189337] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKA (20190816/dspkginit-438)
[    0.241532] NetLabel: Initializing
[    0.241532] NetLabel:  domain hash size = 128
[    0.241532] NetLabel:  protocols = UNLABELED CIPSOv4 CALIPSO
[    0.241532] NetLabel:  unlabeled traffic allowed by default
[    0.263457] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.264353] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.264358] NET: Registered protocol family 44
[    0.900022] i8042: Failed to disable AUX port, but continuing anyway... Is this a SiS?
[    1.159093] drop_monitor: Initializing network drop monitor service
[    1.159264] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    1.166808] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    1.167327] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    1.317029] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    1.322174] libphy: r8169: probed
[    1.322479] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl, 90:2b:34:a8:68:33, XID 2c9, IRQ 29
[    1.322481] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    1.347383] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
[    6.023637] EXT4-fs (sdb8): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   12.849016] nvidia_uvm: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   28.212097] RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet r8169-300:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-300:00, irq=IGNORE)
[   28.411194] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[   66.044219] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlxc025e9252691: link becomes ready
[   80.283089] audit: type=1107 audit(1609624021.597:40): pid=704 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.12" pid=1935 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=705 peer_label="unconfined"
[   85.073199] audit: type=1107 audit(1609613231.276:41): pid=704 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1935 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=718 peer_label="unconfined"
[   85.074014] audit: type=1107 audit(1609613231.280:42): pid=704 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1935 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=718 peer_label="unconfined"
[   86.008967] audit: type=1107 audit(1609613232.212:43): pid=704 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1935 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=718 peer_label="unconfined"
[   86.009749] audit: type=1107 audit(1609613232.216:44): pid=704 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.10" pid=1935 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=718 peer_label="unconfined"
[ 5477.000328] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.048.00-NAPI loaded
[ 5477.022669] r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[ 5477.025670] r8168  Copyright (C) 2019  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
[ 5477.046766] r8168 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
[ 5538.639136] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlxc025e9252691: link becomes ready
[ 6135.165666] r8169 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[ 6135.172150] libphy: r8169: probed
[ 6135.172488] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl, 90:2b:34:a8:68:33, XID 2c9, IRQ 29
[ 6135.172491] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9200 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[ 6135.177699] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
[ 6135.214172] RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet r8169-300:00: attached PHY driver [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-300:00, irq=IGNORE)
[ 6135.419444] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Down
[ 6346.442036] r8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver 8.048.00-NAPI loaded
[ 6346.464463] r8168: This product is covered by one or more of the following patents: US6,570,884, US6,115,776, and US6,327,625.
[ 6346.465981] r8168  Copyright (C) 2019  Realtek NIC software team <nicfae@realtek.com> 
[ 6346.501945] r8168 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0
```

Comment: если боишься - сделай бэкап файла

Comment: А причем тут промежутки времени, нагрузка на сеть, установленная ОС, и прочие косвенные параметры, которые никак не отражаются на результате пробы скорости соединения (или отражаются субъективно)? Вы в курсе, что сделанные две пробы в подряд могут дать такой результат и на одной ОС и в одно время?

Comment: Я делал несколько тестов на одной и на другой ОС. Разница была примерно такой же. Я не очень разбираюсь в подобном, извинясь за свою глупость в этом и за свои вопросы.

Comment: если для соедиединения используете протокол pptp, то совет просто идиотский — во-первых, уж точно не такими варварскими средствами надо добавлять опции запуска прогарммы pptp. для этого есть «провайдерский» файл, во-вторых, советуемые опции аж никак не смогут повлиять на скорость передачи. // а если не используете — так просто вообще «не в тему». // в тему будет обращение к провайдеру с изложением вашей проблемы. // ну, и конечно, все эти спидтесты с их измерениями в попугаях — напрасная трата времени. для теста скорости используйте реальное получение-отправку информации.

Comment: Про протокол ```pptp```, сразу извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, где можно это посмотреть?

Comment: *Про протокол pptp, сразу извиняюсь за глупый вопрос, где можно это посмотреть?* — в инструкции по подключению от вашего провайдера.

Comment: Буду наверное звонить потом провайдеру, разбираться будем в чем может быть проблема. Если что-то узнаю - напишу.

Comment: Проблему с сетевыми драйверами в Ubuntu подобными методами решить нельзя. Есть изобретатели, что вообще win обертки для них юзают, чтобы решить проблемы худшей связи для Linux.

Comment: И что тогда делать? Искать эти "обертки"?

Comment: товарищ Assur наоборот привёл пример как **не** надо делать. Обёртки - это лишь обёртки. От того, в какую обёртку завернуть конфету не зависит, будет конфетка вкусной или не очень. Так же и здесь. От внешнего вида, то, что под капотом не изменится.

Comment: А, понял, благодарю за пояснение!

Comment: кстати, у вас такая низкая скорость на ubuntu только при скачивании пакетов или  при скачивании файлов в браузере тоже?

Comment: Везде, где требуется интернет скорость наблюдается низкая

Comment: Вот сейчас по-быстрому проверил:```~$ speedtest-cli --simple --bytes
Ping: 7.276 ms
Download: 0.10 Mbyte/s
Upload: 0.72 Mbyte/s```

Comment: а firmware стоит?

Comment: Не знаю, где это можно посмотреть?

Comment: dmesg посмотри на ошибки

Comment: ```0.188105] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, While resolving a named reference package element - LNKC (20190816/dspkginit-438)```
Вот одна, остальные похожие

Comment: Получается firmware у меня стоит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решить проблему помогло:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
~$ sudo modprobe r8168
```

Далее необходимо перезагрузить устройство.
Также, после перезагрузки можно проверить скорость следующей командой:
`~$ speedtest-cli --simple --bytes`

Которая выводит:

```
Ping: 6.652 ms
Download: 3.32 Mbyte/s
Upload: 2.27 Mbyte/s
```