# После установки ubuntu скорость интернета стала ниже и нет значка wifi

Tags: ubuntu

Образ ubuntu 20.04

Я сделал следующие шаги (у меня RTL8111): [Упала скорость интернета на Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226156/%d0%a3%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-ubuntu-20-04-lts)

после этого скорость не увеличилась и значка wifi нет. Интернет идет через usb модем, но его скорость 5мб.с

проверил скорость командой

> speedtest-cli --simple --bytes
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что вы хотите получить? На [RTL8111](https://lekensteyn.nl/files/realtek/rtl-pcie-gbe-10ec-8168-rev02.jpg) нет Wifi.

Comment: Проблемой оказалось мое интернет соединение, я проверил на другом компьютере оно с такой же скоростью работает

Comment: в любом случае, значка wifi нет, и нужно решить эту проблему. и ставить драйвера, которые не понятно где искать

Comment: Всех драйверов не поставишь, надо выяснять какое оборудование отвечает за Wifi.

Comment: Навскидку попробуйте установить пакет `firmware-b43-installer` и перезагрузить компьютер, может повезет...